# Memcached - "No Memcached servers added" after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached, laravel-5.1

**Does upgrading from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 affect multi-server memcached?**

I have a Laravel 5.1 application which utilizes `memcached` to manage sessions across multiple servers, specifically two web servers and a database server.

After upgrading the OS on each server from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and installing the latest version of mariadb (10.1.*), our laravel application now returns the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   No Memcached servers added.

My config files have not changed and neither have the ip addresses of any of the servers. Debugging laravel's `MemcachedConnector.php`shows the server details being passed to the `Memcached` class but the output of `Memcached::getVersion()` returns `false`.

I am at a loss as to why this has suddenly stopped working, any assitance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your 16.04 installation has a "memcached" package:

`dpkg -s memcached`

If you see a message "dpkg-query: package 'memcached' is not installed and no information is available", install it by

`sudo apt-get install memcached`